# Glib Variant Tuple Deserialization

Tags: c++, glib, variant, stdtuple

I am trying to de-serialize below Tuple, but getting issues while getting internal vector variant.
initial 2 values are retrieved but vector variant is giving me some trouble I am not able to understand why its not working

```
Glib::Variant < std::tuple < std::uint32_t, // First unsigned integer
  std::uint32_t, // First unsigned integer
  std::vector < // Array of dictionaries
  std::tuple < std::uint32_t, // Inner unsigned integer
  std::int32_t, // Inner unsigned integer
  std::vector < // Array of dictionaries
  std::map < Glib::ustring, // Dictionary key (string)
  Glib::VariantBase // Dictionary value (variant)
  >
  > > > , std::vector < // Array of dictionaries
  std::map < Glib::ustring, // Dictionary key (string)
  Glib::VariantBase // Dictionary value (variant)
  >
  > > > response_variant;

//here is my de - serialization code:

  Glib::Variant < std::uint32_t > firstVariant;
Glib::Variant < std::uint32_t > secondVariant;

call_result.get_child(firstVariant, 0);
std::uint32_t first_value = firstVariant.get();
std::cout << "fist_value: " << first_value << std::endl;

call_result.get_child(secondVariant, 1);
std::uint32_t second_value = secondVariant.get();
std::cout << "second_value: " << second_value << std::endl;

Glib::Variant <
  std::vector <
  std::tuple < std::uint32_t, std::int32_t,
  std::vector <
  std::map < Glib::ustring,
  Glib::VariantBase >> > >
  >
  thirdVariant;

call_result.get_child(thirdVariant, 2);

// Check if the variant is an array
if (thirdVariant.get_type_string() == "a(uia{sv})") {

  std::size_t innerTupleCount = thirdVariant.get_n_children();
  std::cout << "innerTupleCount: " << innerTupleCount << std::endl;
  Glib::Variant < std::tuple < std::uint32_t, std::int32_t, std::vector < std::map < Glib::ustring, Glib::VariantBase >>> > baseVariant;

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < innerTupleCount; ++i) {

    Glib::Variant < std::tuple < std::uint32_t, std::int32_t, std::vector < std::map < Glib::ustring, Glib::VariantBase >>> > tupleVariant;
    //thirdVariant.get_child(tupleVariant, i); //compilation error no matching function for call
    //tupleVariant = thirdVariant.get_child(i); //Compilation error no match for 'operator='
  }
} else {
  std::cerr << "Unexpected variant type: " << thirdVariant.get_type_string() << std::endl;
}
```

I am able to get number of children of vector but when I tried to retrive tuple code give me compilation errors. May be I am not able to understand the object here !

I tried to do below, But getting compilation errors:

```
 //thirdVariant.get_child(tupleVariant, i); //compilation error no matching function for call
    //tupleVariant = thirdVariant.get_child(i); //Compilation error no match for 'operator='
```

Looking for help, thanks in advance.

I tried multiple ways but nothing works

```
 //thirdVariant.get_child(tupleVariant, i); //compilation error no matching function for call
    //tupleVariant = thirdVariant.get_child(i); //Compilation error no match for 'operator='
```